# Fedora26 Systemd script not get executed

Tags: fedora, systemd

I created a simple systemd unit file(sysupdate.service) with following content to automate system updates, but got frustrated by complexity.

/etc/systemd/system/sysupdate.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=update system preferably after dnfdragora finished checking update
After=syslog.target network.target network-online.target auditd.service

[Service]
StandardInput=null
ExecStart=/mnt/0/sysupdate.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

sysupdate.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec  &>> /mnt/0/sysupdate.log

echo $(date)

sudo dnf upgrade -y
echo '$?':$?
sudo youtube-dl -U
echo '$?':$?
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
echo '$?':$?

echo $(date)
```

The normal user has write privilege inside /mnt/0/.
sysupdate.sh was set "chmod uo+x".

Every time I commented out "service Type", "After" or "user" in service file, I always do:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

The expected log file "/mnt/0/sysupdate.log" never gets created.

Why such simple automation is so difficult to get done?!

Latest status:
Even I executed as root the 2 lines of code given by "journalctl -xe":

```
SELinux is preventing (pdate.sh) from execute access on the file sysupdate.sh.

                                                      *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

                                                      If you believe that (pdate.sh) should be allowed execute access on the sysupdate.sh file by defa
                                                      Then you should report this as a bug.
                                                      You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                                      Do
                                                      allow this access for now by executing:
                                                      # ausearch -c '(pdate.sh)' --raw | audit2allow -M my-pdatesh
                                                      # semodule -X 300 -i my-pdatesh.pp
```

There's still permission denied error in journal log.

I temporarily got it work by setting SELinux permissive.

Comment: What does `sudo systemctl status sysupdate.service` say? What about `sudo journalctl -o verbose -u sysupdate.service`?

Comment: Also, if this is more than an academic exercise, take a look at [DNF Automatic](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/automatic.html).

Comment: Excerpt of journalctl -o verbose -u sysupdate.service:
...
`PRIORITY=4
SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=systemd
_UID=0
_GID=0
_PID=1
_TRANSPORT=journal
_CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
_COMM=systemd
_EXE=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
_SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/init.scope
_SYSTEMD_UNIT=init.scope
_SYSTEMD_SLICE=-.slice
_SELINUX_CONTEXT=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
_CMDLINE=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 24
UNIT=sysupdate.service
CODE_FILE=src/core/service.c
CODE_LINE=1481
CODE_FUNC=service_enter_dead
MESSAGE=sysupdate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
`

Comment: @mattdm:Thank you very much for kind recommendation to DNF Automatic, I really want to get my first systemd toy script work.

Comment: @mattdm:Thank you.systemctl status is:\n
`Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sysupdate.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)\n
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-09-16 08:42:01 JST; 2min 21s ago\n
Process: 1255 ExecStart=/mnt/0/sysupdate.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)\n
Main PID: 1255 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)\n
localhost.localdomain systemd[1255]: sysupdate.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /mnt/0/sysupdate.sh: Permission denied`.\nEven after I added "User=<everyday user>\n
Group=<everyday user>" in the service file.

Comment: I **temporarily** got it work by setting SELinux permissive. I don't want to turn off SELinux permanently.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense — I can see why running random scripts from `/mnt` might not be allowed by the default policy. This is better as a question on https://unix.stackexchange.com — "How can I make something denied by SELinux be allowed?"